# Hive select * shows 0 but count(1) show returns millions of rows

Tags: hadoop, hive

I create a hive external table and add a partition by

```
create external table tbA (
  colA int,
  colB string,
  ...)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `day` string)
stored as parquet;

alter table tbA add partition(day= '2021-09-04');
```

Then I put a parquet file to the target HDFS directory by `hdfs dfs -put ...`

I can get expected results using `select * from tbA` in `IMPALA`.

In `Hive`, I can get correct result when using
`select count(1) from tbA`
However, when I use

`select * from tbA limit 10`

It returns no result at all.

If anything is wrong with the parquet file or the directory, `IMPALA` should not get the correct result and `Hive` can count out row numbers... Why `select * from ...` shows nothing? Any help is appreciated.

---

In addition,
running `select distinct day from tbA`, it returns `2021-09-04`

running `select * from tbA`, it returns data with day = `2021-09-04`

It seems this partition is not recognized correctly? I retried to drop the partition and use `msck repair table` but still not working...

Comment: In impala can you try `invalidate metadata tab`? And then check your sqls.

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy. I tried your cmd and impala still works as expected. Now Hive cannot show data.

Comment: in hive, you can try `analyze table tab compute statistics`.